# Cron job won't run (pgrep issue)

Tags: shell-script, cron, pgrep

I'm running a cron job every minute, which launches a bash shell script:

```
# Automatically reboot the server if it goes down
* * * * * /root/auto-restart.sh
```

I can manually run the script, but whenever I try running it through a cron job it won't run. I've debugged a bit and found this command to be the culprit:

```
pgrep -fcl auto-restart.sh
```

To summarize, when run manually, that command returns the correct value and only lists auto-restart.sh if the script's currently running (as it should).

But when the cron job launches it, it shows the output of `pgrep -fl auto-restart.sh` as follows (when it's running):

```
3110 sh
3111 auto-restart.sh
```

Here's the bit of code I'm working with:

```
scriptcheck=`pgrep -fcl auto-restart.sh`
if [ $scriptcheck -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "auto-restart.sh script already in use. Terminating.."
    #cron job debugging..
    echo "[DEBUG] scriptcheck returning greater than 1" > /tmp/debug.output
    echo "[DEBUG] Value of scriptcheck: ${scriptcheck}" >> /tmp/debug.output
    echo "[DEBUG] contents:" >> /tmp/debug.output
    pgrep -fl auto-restart.sh >> /tmp/debug.output
    exit
fi
```

Complete script here: https://pastebin.com/bDyzxFXq

Answer (score 5):

When `cron` runs `/root/auto-restart.sh`, it runs it using `sh`, along the lines of `sh -c /root/auto-restart.sh`. Since you’ve used the `-f` option with `pgrep`, `pgrep` looks for `auto-restart.sh` anywhere in the running processes’ command lines; so it matches `auto-restart.sh` as well as `sh -c /root/auto-restart.sh`. The latter appears as plain `sh` in the output of `pgrep -l`.

```
pgrep -c auto-restart.sh
```

will give you the behaviour you’re after. (I dropped `-l` because it’s meaningless with `-c`.)

(Your server probably has a [watchdog timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer), which might be more appropriate — although I imagine that if the server is still running sufficiently well to run cron jobs, but is otherwise considered down, then the watchdog wouldn’t trip.)